# Video formats (player) flash (windows 10)

Tags: html, flash, video, titanium

I have an application for Windows, Mac OS and Linux, built in Titanium Desktop and TideSDK 1.3.1 beta, and it still works!!

Since flash player is deprecated in most of modern browsers, and the source code of the application it's html, css and js, every time that I add a mp4 video to the sources folder, it doesn't play because isn't in html5, even after I've added the  tag and require the html5shiv to all of my project files.

In windows 10, the swf videos are ok, but the mp4 files won't play.

I've tried to add the following plugins, but still no success:

- jwplayer
- flowplayer

The videos must be player without internet, from the sources folder of the application.

Any thoughts?

Comment: SWF is not a video format. You can write code for a video player & display code result with _Flash Player_ **plugin**. Are you saying you can display SWF applications? So use a Flash made video player to play the MP4 files. I suspect the video tag is not working here because there is no decoder (the browsers have in-built code to decode that audio/video data from MP4). You just wrote one sentence of HTML5 pointing to a URL and that's not enough.

Comment: My videos are in mp4 format, I was using a SWF player to play them, this always worked, but in windows 10 it doesn't run, but if it's an online video it does play, I think this is happening because the Windows permissions.

Comment: My workaround for this was converting the mp4 files to swf, but as this is not an video format, the player controls won't work